# Disabling IE8 blue border arround icon

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have attached image to button with css style.

```
 .a-icon {
    background: url('../a.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;
 }

 .b-icon {
    background: url('../b.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;
 }
```

In Firefox it looks fine, but in IE8 blue border appears around icon, when button becomes disabled. I have tried adding border: none and so on, but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be padding, try setting the background colour, does the colour of the 'border' change?

Comment: no the color of border does not change

Answer (score 2):

All links with `img` inside have a blue border on IE lte than 9, add to Your css global style for this tags.

```
a img {
 border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.a-icon,
.a-icon img,
.b-icon,
.b-icon img {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: As i said, this does not change anything ;/

Comment: did you try outline: 0? send link to your site

Comment: Yeah, i have tried. This is private website, so i can`t send you link. Maybe the problem is that i`m using extjs framework and it does some changes to it.

Comment: http://s11.postimg.org/h1eexvztr/Untitled.png top one is on ie8, bottom one firefox

Comment: it is not CSS problem, it looks like IE8 can't show your png correctly, try remade your png or set background: transparent to that img in css

Comment: if i add `background: transparent` the whole icon just hides and does not appear. If i remove `background: transparent` and use your above code, nothing happens. The border still exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the solution that you are looking for. If I understood you right, the problem is with the link border that is around the image. So you have to remove that.
So try this:

```
 a img {
    border:0;
 }
```

Hope it helps